# Why are my drives referred to as '(hda0,msdos5)' etc in grub instead of (hda0,5), (hda0,sda5) etc that you usually see?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm fiddling about trying to get a multiboot system (win7, ubuntu, lion) on one drive working with grub 2, but was wondering what the msdos part meant on my system. I don't see it like that on any of the examples online.

Comment: You'll probably see it in the official GRUB documentation, though.  I believe they made that change a while back, along with some others. There's a lot of outdated examples online, not to mention many that are downright wrong or convoluted hacks.  There is no rule that people need to actually understand what they are writing about, and it shows.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to distinguish between MBR-style partitions and GPT-style partitions.

For "old" MBR partitions, the prefix is `msdos`. For GPT, the prefix is `gpt`.

Note that partitions are numbered starting from 1 in Grub2, while they were numbered starting from 0 in previous versions.

See the Arch [Grub2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Notes_for_current_GRUB_Legacy_users) wiki entry for more on this.