# What is `/dev/sda0`? Is it a standard thing?

Tags: partition, udev, devices, block-device, history

While trying to understand [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/705181/108618), I encountered `/dev/sda0` being mentioned.

I have some experience in Linux and I'm used to this scheme where `sda`, `sdb`, … are devices and `sda1`, `sda2`, … , `sdb1`, `sdb2`, … are partitions (each inside the respective device). In this scheme `sda0`, `sdb0`, … do not appear. I don't recall seeing `sda0` ever.

Still `sda0` appears [on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=sda0), [on Super User](https://superuser.com/search?q=sda0) and elsewhere. Where it appears, it almost always seems to be the first partition, i.e. the partition I would expect to appear as `sda1` in the scheme I'm used to.

On the other hand in Debian 10 I can see `major,minor` numbers as `8,1` for `sda1`, `8,2` for `sda2` etc. Thus if anyone asked me what `sda0` might be, I would say `8,0` which is already assigned to `sda`. This reasoning would make `sda0` equivalent to `sda`, the whole device. I guess these numbers are specific to Linux and they may be different in a non-Linux Unix(-like) OS, so the reasoning may not apply there.

In the Internet I have found few appearances of `sda0` used as a whole device. The examples are quite obscure though, they may be due to typos or somebody being wrong.

Anyway, the question is: **is/was `/dev/sda0` a standard thing?** If so, what is/was it? (can/could it be a whole device?). Under what circumstances is/was it a standard thing? (e.g. specific OS, some old kernel, specific driver, inside a virtual machine, some obsolete(?) udev config or so).

I'm hoping for answers that will give me enough insight, so the next time I see `/dev/sda0` I will be able to tell to myself: 'Oh, this guy is probably using …'; or maybe: 'Caution! Custom config ahead'.

---

<sup>Side note: I have also found mentions of `/dev/hda0` and a scheme that starts enumerating from `hda1`. I totally cannot tell if it's closely related (a parallel) to what I observed for `/dev/sda*` or just a coincidence.</sup>

Comment: It might be a common typo or deliberate obfuscation. I sometimes use `/dev/sdx` just to avoid people formatting their `/dev/sda` in a bad copy-paste.

Comment: Using a site-search on pastebincom found 1000+ matches for `sda1` but only a single occurrence of `sda0` - in a paste with lots of typos so probably OCR error or a bad serial connection. If it exists in any flavor of Unix, it should be more exotic...

Comment: if you have more than 41 drives, you might have a device named `/dev/sdao` (lower case **o** , as in Oscar, letter)

Comment: @frostschutz I tend to use `/dev/sdX` or `/dev/sdaX` to tell people to change the X

Comment: Developers start counting at "0", IT guys start at "1"...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I’m not aware of `/dev/sda0` ever being a standard device name, even on other Unix systems. And as far as I can tell, references to `sda0` are likely mistakes rather than indications of a custom setup.

Even in cases where the devices are named in output, users still confuse the numbers. For example, [this forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240917) explicitly lists `sda1` to `sda3` in the quoted output, yet the title mentions `sda0`. Similarly, [Why are my drives referred to as '(hda0,msdos5)' etc in grub instead of (hda0,5), (hda0,sda5) etc that you usually see?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36237/86440) refers to `hda0` (which has also never been a standard device name, as far as I know) even though Grub uses `hd0` etc.

The Linux kernel publishes [the list of device assignments](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html); this describes how partitions are handled:

> For partitions, add to the whole disk device number:
>
> | Value | Device | Usage |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | `/dev/hd?` | Whole disk |
> | 1 | `/dev/hd?1` | First partition |
> | 2 | `/dev/hd?2` | Second partition |
> | … | … | … |
> | 63 | `/dev/hd?63` | 63rd partition |

SCSI disks (`/dev/sd?`) are handled in the same way:

> Partitions are handled in the same way as for IDE disks (see major number 3) except that the limit on partitions is 15.

As you can see, there’s no provision for a 0-numbered partition; the “0th” device is the whole disk, represented without a numeric suffix.

(Note that “SCSI disks”, aka `sd?`, are used for many non-SCSI devices; see [Why CentOS converts ATA bus to scsi bus?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/703094/86440) for some of the history.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136909/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-what-is-dev-sda0-is-it-a-standard-thing).

Answer (score 6):

I've seen this, on a system without udev, one for which mknod would not second-guess you (I used a system for awhile where putting in the wrong major+minor was fixed by makenod somehow), and using the 2.0 kernel; /dev/hda0 was the whole disk device.

The systems I used at the time were various strange floppy-based distros that couldn't build from source even if you wanted to; I used to mostly use muLinux at the time, but this wasn't that one and I'd be hard pressed to find it again. I was involved in the community for awhile. The thing about all of these is they were hand-built. There's no standardization, no upgrade, no package manager, no nothing. The /dev/hda0 device must have come from the guy who built it believing that's what it should be.

I would be astonished if this bizarre naming convention lived into the udev era.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear whether your question is Linux-specific, but in case not, a FreeBSD system would regard `/dev/da0` as the first disk drive on the system, at least for SCSI (and USB) drives, and perhaps other drive types where the device driver presents the device as a SCSI-like unit.  ATA/SATA (and historically, ATAPI) drives would be `/dev/adaN`, where `N` >= 0.

Note that `/dev/da0` is a full-drive device, not a partition device.  Subdivisions of unit 0 would be `/dev/da0sX` for MBR slices (X>=1), or `/dev/da0pX` (X>=1) for GPT partitions.

DA is a mnemonic for a Direct Access device, or random access, in that any block of the device is equally addressable.  In contrast, FreeBSD uses `sa` device driver nodes of the form `/dev/saN` for Sequential Access devices, e.g. tape drives.

Comment: You don't happen to mean FreeBSD when you say "BSD", do you? Because e.g. [OpenBSD looks to have](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html) `sd` and `wd`, and (unlike those two) the [man pages don't know about `da`](https://man.openbsd.org/da). NetBSD looks similar to OpenBSD in this.

Comment: @ilkkachu I took the liberty of fixing that as it clearly does not reflect the device names found on other BSD systems.  Most OpenBSD systems would use `sd0` as the first SCSI-like drive, with partition letters `a`, `b` (swap), `c` (whole disk), `d`, `e`, etc. up to `p`.  NetBSD is similar but different.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you for your help illustrating that unit 0 is not unusual in disk devices.

Comment: @JimL., the question specifically mentioned `sda0`, though. (not just `sd0` or `da0`)

Comment: @ilkkachu Indeed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no**. The interface promises between kernel and userspace does not include the device **numbers**. it may be any numerical value and may even differ when you reboot to a newer kernel. Therefore you should never rely on them.